# I made a CLI menu for my program, but after the first input, I can not give another input to the menu

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is the code of the menu:

```
async function showMenu(page, browser){
    console.log(
        '1 : Send email' + '\n' +
        '2 : Delete sent emails'  + '\n' +
        '3 : Exit'  + '\n'
        );
    process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
    process.stdin.on('readable', checkMenu);

    function checkMenu() {
        var input = process.stdin.read();
        if(input !== null) {
            switch(input.trim()) {
                case '1': sendEmail(page); break;
                case '2': browser.close(); break;
                default: showMenu();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After making the first input, which is case 1, the sendEmail function executes and sends an email, but after that function stops running, the menu can not accept another input. I doesn't show any error messages, I just can't type a new input into the console.